# Filter out records within n days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure how to title this challenge..

I want to mark (to filter on later) certain records, partitioned by a TypeID column, where they are observed within **n** days (in this example 3) of the first record's date value in the partitioned dataset. This is straightforward, but in the same partitioned set, if more records appear **after** the 3 days limit - the new "first" record of this group should start a new chain to mark all following records within 3 days. And so on..

I have illustrated the desired output in this screenshot, where I want to flag/filter out the rows marked with yellow. All other rows are to be kept.

[image]

I've sprayed and prayed with window functions etc., but can't seem to find an elegant solution.. How would you approach this issue with T-SQL?

sqlfiddle is not responding with sql-server atm, so posting the DDL code here:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[testTable];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable](
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [CustID] [int] NULL,
    [TransTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (1, 9362, 1, CAST(N'2018-01-11' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (2, 9362, 1, CAST(N'2018-01-22' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (3, 9362, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-04' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (4, 9362, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-07' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (5, 9362, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-09' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (6, 9362, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-22' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (7, 9362, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-23' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (8, 9362, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-24' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (9, 9362, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-26' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (10, 9362, 3, CAST(N'2018-01-22' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (11, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-01-01' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (12, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-01-02' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (13, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-01-02' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (14, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-01-04' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (15, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-01-07' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (16, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-01-17' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (17, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-02-08' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testTable] ([RowID], [CustID], [TransTypeID], [Date]) VALUES (18, 9362, 5, CAST(N'2018-02-18' AS Date))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[testTable] OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do this with a recursive CTE. First `SELECT` all rows with the minimum date within the group. That can be done using `row_number()`. Then recursively `UNION ALL` the rows with the minimum date within the group where the date is greater that the maximum date already in the result plus 3 days, thus skipping 3 days. Again `row_number()` can be used for that, and `dateadd()` for the date arithmetic.

```
WITH [cte]
AS
(
SELECT [x].[RowID],
       [x].[CustID],
       [x].[TransTypeId],
       [x].[Date]
       FROM (SELECT [testTable].[RowID],
                    [testTable].[CustID],
                    [testTable].[TransTypeId],
                    [testTable].[Date],
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [testTable].[CustId],
                                                    [testTable].[TransTypeID]
                                       ORDER BY [testTable].[Date]) [row#]
                    FROM [dbo].[testTable]) [x]
       WHERE [x].[row#] = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT [x].[RowID],
       [x].[CustID],
       [x].[TransTypeId],
       [x].[Date]
       FROM (SELECT [testTable].[RowID],
                    [testTable].[CustID],
                    [testTable].[TransTypeId],
                    [testTable].[Date],
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [testTable].[CustId],
                                                    [testTable].[TransTypeID]
                                       ORDER BY [testTable].[Date]) [row#]
                    FROM [dbo].[testTable]
                         INNER JOIN [cte]
                                    ON [cte].[CustId] = [testTable].[CustId]
                                       AND [cte].[TransTypeId] = [testTable].[TransTypeID]
                                       AND dateadd(day, 3, [cte].[Date]) < [testTable].[Date]) [x]
       WHERE [x].[row#] = 1
)
SELECT *
       FROM [cte]
       ORDER BY [cte].[CustID],
                [cte].[TransTypeID],
                [cte].[Date];
```

Result:

```
RowID | CustID | TransTypeId | Date               
----: | -----: | ----------: | :------------------
    1 |   9362 |           1 | 11/01/2018 00:00:00
    2 |   9362 |           1 | 22/01/2018 00:00:00
    3 |   9362 |           2 | 04/01/2018 00:00:00
    5 |   9362 |           2 | 09/01/2018 00:00:00
    6 |   9362 |           2 | 22/01/2018 00:00:00
    9 |   9362 |           2 | 26/01/2018 00:00:00
   10 |   9362 |           3 | 22/01/2018 00:00:00
   11 |   9362 |           5 | 01/01/2018 00:00:00
   15 |   9362 |           5 | 07/01/2018 00:00:00
   16 |   9362 |           5 | 17/01/2018 00:00:00
   17 |   9362 |           5 | 08/02/2018 00:00:00
   18 |   9362 |           5 | 18/02/2018 00:00:00
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8e56f7b1ad6f95766d72a6de402864ca)

(I assumed the groups are defined not only by `[TransTypeID]` but also by `[CustID]`. That wasn't really clear to me. If my assumption is wrong remove `[CustID]` from the `PARTITION BY` clauses.)

Comment: Yes, the CustID is also part of the group. It works flawlessly! I wanted to mark the records though, not filter straight away. So I inserted this into a temp table, joined it into the original and marked the rows without a match with 0, else 1, etc. Nice!